# Issues with CVX package for optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, math-software, cvx

I am trying to use the [cvx](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/index.html) package for optimization. However, I am having some issues with it. I have a variable $X$ which is a matrix but I cannot add $X^{-1}$ in the objective function. What should I do? Is it even possible to use it or it violates the definition of semi definite programming and hence cannot be included

Comment: I believe you'll get better answers elsewhere. Like http://ask.cvxr.com/questions/ or SciComp